# Can you walk me through how to download and install Windows?

Tags: boot, usb-drive, windows-10

For the last few months I've been running an HP Compaq 6000 Pro on Linux Ubuntu. I use a laptop that ran Windows 8.1 but I swapped ro this Ubuntu since that motherboard on the laptop fried. I tried it and while I can certainly see the freedom and liberty it offers, I can't fully appreciate it. I've just come to the terms that it isn't for me and I would like to switch to Windows.

So, since this community is pretty helpful and seems to specialize with anything related to Ubuntu, how do I do it without ruining the computer?

P.S:
*I read something about being able to download a "disc" something from the Windows website [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) but that it needs a CD or USB drive with at least 5 gigs of free space to be stored. It said something about getting 30 days free before needing a license key to progress but, as you now know, I'm terribly inexperienced at any of this.*

**Please... like I'm an idiot...** (I got this computer from a relative and the extent of my knowledge on booting is *literally* pressing F1 in the boot up menu.)

Comment: **Close voters:** This is not a dupe of the suggested question, as the OP wants to completely replace Ubuntu with Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your computer supports booting from a USB drive you can buy a Windows 10 installation USB straight from the Microsoft online store. Then all you do is stick the drive in a USB port on your computer, turn it on, and the windows installation will start, all you have to do is answer a few questions about your username, etc... Before you do that though you will want to copy all of your data you want to save off of your ubuntu machine onto a flash drive or external hard drive as the windows installation will erase the hard drive to install windows on it.

After installing Windows, you will need to download any missing driver's from HP's website.

Comment: The OP wants to dual-boot, not replace Ubuntu

Comment: The first paragraph says "I came to terms and its not for me, I would like to switch to windows"

Comment: My apologies, that second paragraph threw me off. I think I'm going remove it from the question.

Comment: No worries, I read it a few times myself!

Comment: How do I tell if it supports USB drive?

Comment: @J.Sabere - All modern computers support booting from a USB drive

Comment: @Android Dev  Oh, okay.

Comment: A quick search about the computer shows it supports it, you could make sure by entering the BIOS and viewing the boot order. I also noticed it is an older computer, so you will want to make sure you know if the processor is 32-bit or 64 bit before purchasing windows 10

Comment: @nullmeta Welcome to AskUbuntu, by the way! As a new user, if there's anything I can do to help you get started, then just let me know :)

Comment: @nullmeta -  I recommend that you thoroughly read the Help Center, as it answers a lot of the FAQs: http://askubuntu.com/help

Comment: @nullmeta I checked it before as I went to download another software in the past and needed to know. It is 64bit-much to my surprise when I learned it.